# Include file to VS2017 c++ project by condition

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, c-preprocessor

I am trying to build the c/c++ project in VS2017
[https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=psqlodbc.git;a=blob;f=winbuild/psqlodbc.vcxproj;h=c54c93007c07c2b13bbea4ede14a6ee0e11fdf5a;hb=c54c93007c07c2b13bbea4ede14a6ee0e11fdf5a][1]

There are conditions in the project file

```
<ClCompile Include="$(srcPath)odbcapi30.c" />\r
<ClCompile Condition="'$(ANSI_VERSION)'=='no'" Include="$(srcPath)odbcapi30w.c" />\r
<ClCompile Condition="'$(ANSI_VERSION)'=='no'" Include="$(srcPath)odbcapiw.c" />\r
```

I have created 
Unicode Debug/Release
ANSI Debug/Release
configurattions
and in the project properties->c\c++->Preprocessor I have added the ANSI_VERSION=no for Unicode and ANSI_VERSION=yes for ANSI.

But for any Platform/Configuration I see these files in the Solution Explorer and they are compiled by VS2017. How to include these files into project when condition is true only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition requires that ANSI_VERSION is a MSBuild property. These are different from the C++ Preprocessor definitions (which are inputs used when compiling a file but not used by MSBUILD when testing for which files to compile - strictly speaking its used by the pre-processor but its part of the compile step from an msbuild point of view)

You can set the ANSI_VERSION as an MSBUILD property in your project file:-

For example:-

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ANSI_VERSION>no</ANSI_VERSION>
    <ANSI_VERSION Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ANSI_DEBUG'">yes</ANSI_VERSION>
    <ANSI_VERSION Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ANSI_RELEASE'">yes</ANSI_VERSION>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The above defaults ANSI_VERSION to no and overrides to yes when condition is met, but you could just as well test each possible configuration in turn instead if you prefer.

The conditions could also be combined into a single condition with an or if you prefer.

Personally I'd use true/false rather than yes/no. With true false you can just test the property as a Boolean rather than compare to string (although maybe this also works with yes/no - but I haven't tried that)

Edit in response to question:
The above conditionally excludes the files from the build, excluding them from the display is a little different as it would require the UI to re-parse the projects to update the list of files. You may find things works better for you to create a filter in the project for these files (i.e. right click on project in solution view and use Add->New Filter). Then conditionally use the ExcludeFromBuild setting to control which configurations actually compile them instead of making the CLCompile include conditional, something like:-

```
<ClCompile Include="SomeFile.cpp">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
</ClCompile>
```

Comment: Thanks! I see the important difference. Using this way I can include files by condition and do not see them in VS explorer?